# Using a generic type inside another generic in C# class that uses SQLite db in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics, xamarin

I have a simple data base control handler class.

It uses a `SQLiteConnection`. I have several tables in my SQLite db.

Now I want to write a generic simple accessor function for all tables of a specific type that use an int Id as primary key.  Therefore I have a base class  `TableWithIntId` that always has an `int Id` as primary key.

My simplified code is:

```
private SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection;

public T LoadRecord<T>(int id) where T : Database.TableWithIntId
{
    try
    {
        return (from objTable in sqliteConnection.Table<T>()
            where objTable.Id == id
            select objTable).First();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get the following error:

*error CS0310: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Table()'*

This is confusing for me, because T is non abstract and has an automatic default  constructor.

```
public class TableWithIntId
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify `new()` constraint for `T` in `where` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint `where T : Database.TableWithIntId` only states that `T` must derive from `Database.TableWithIntId`. But derived classes don't necessarily have a parameterless constructor (if you give them only constructors with parameters).

Add a [`new()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) constraint to solve that:

```
public T LoadRecord<T>(int id) where T : Database.TableWithIntId, new()
```

That restricts `T` to classes with parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [new Constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

```
  public T LoadRecord<T>(int id) where T : TableWithIntId, new()
    {
       try
       {
           return (from objTable in sqliteConnection.Table<T>()
                   where objTable.Id == id
                   select objTable).First();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
           return null;
       }
   }
```